# An URL is redirected wrongly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hey I have a problem with this url https://jujustukaisen.com/manga/jujutsu-kaisen-chapter-142/. It takes me to the homepage (most of the times) not the right adress. My script does not work because of that. Is there any way to solve it?

```
class CustomError(Exception):
    pass

def generate_comics_urls():
    comics_sites_url = []
    a = "https://jujustukaisen.com/manga/jujustu-kaisen-chapter-{0}/"
    for i in range(1,154):
        comics_sites_url.append(a.format(i))
    return comics_sites_url

comics_urls = ['https://jujustukaisen.com/manga/jujutsu-kaisen-chapter-142/'] #generate_comics_urls()
for chapter, comics_url in enumerate(tqdm(comics_urls), start=1):
    os.mkdir(str(chapter))
    comics_page = requests.get(comics_url)
    if comics_page.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(comics_page.content, "html.parser")
        picture_order = 1
        while True:
            picture_url = soup.find("img",alt="Jujutsu Kaisen, Chapter {0} image {1:0>3}".format(chapter,picture_order))
            picture_order += 1
            if picture_url:
                picture_url = picture_url["src"]
                picture = requests.get(picture_url, stream=True)
                if picture.status_code == 200:
                    picture.raw.decode_content = True
                    fh = open("{0}/{1}.jpg".format(str(chapter),str(picture_order)),"wb")
                    shutil.copyfileobj(picture.raw, fh)
                    fh.close()
                else:
                    raise CustomError(f"IVALID URL - {picture_url} - {comics_url}")
            else:
                break
    else:
        raise CustomError(f"INVALID URL - {comics_url}")
```

Comment: Do you control the website being linked to?

Comment: No I don't I guess I will have to download it by hand, but it is bugging me because from browser it works now but not from python.

Comment: There is likely a header or some set of cookies you are missing in the request, or the user-agent is being denied on sub-paths (assuming the owner of the server doesn't want you scraping their pages). If it "used to work, now doesnt", then this is a common diversion tactic

Comment: The issue is with the Wordpress site, not your code. They either have 301 redirect rules preventing you from viewing it or they have plugin/permalink issues. Consider reaching out to the website owner to resolve

Comment: Well I am not sure, if its because they dont want me to scrape their pages, because it works with about 130 other urls.

Comment: @IneedHELP check below answer

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is kind of funny.

This is your url
https://jujustukaisen.com/manga/jujutsu-kaisen-chapter-142/

This is their url
[https://jujustukaisen.com/manga/juju**s**tu-kaisen-chapter-142/](https://jujustukaisen.com/manga/jujustu-kaisen-chapter-142/)

The difference is the spelling of jujutsu. The website misspelled it so while your spelling is correct, you are hitting an invalid endpoint which redirects you to the index page

It seemed like your `generate_comic_urls` function was correct. What instigated you to manually check 142?

Comment: Thanks man, this is so stupid. I checked all the folders and 142 was one of the empty ones.

Comment: Unlucky accident

Comment: Did you figure out why 142 was skipped?

Comment: They weren't exactly skipped. The code just didn't find any element img with the right alt. That happened with these urls:1,142,148,150,151,152,153,55,6,66,7,70,85,86. The website missspelled these urls.

Answer (score 1):

Url was never skipped at all if you picked it up correctly as below:

```py
import trio
import httpx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

mainurl = "https://jujustukaisen.com/"


async def downloader(client, img):
    if not img.startswith('h'):
        img = re.search(r'data-lazy-src=”(.*?)”', img).group(1)
    print(img) # do whatever from here!


async def worker(channel):
    async with channel:
        async for client, link, nurse in channel:
            r = await client.get(link)
            soup = await get_soup(r.text)
            images = [x['src'] for x in soup.select('.entry-content img')]
            for image in images:
                nurse.start_soon(downloader, client, image)


async def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')


async def get_urls(client):
    r = await client.get(mainurl)
    soup = await get_soup(r.text)
    return [x['href'] for x in soup.select('#ceo_latest_comics_widget-3 a')]


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        links = await get_urls(client)

        sender, receiver = trio.open_memory_channel(0)
        async with receiver:
            for _ in range(5):
                nurse.start_soon(worker, receiver.clone())

            async with sender:
                for link in links:
                    await sender.send([client, link, nurse])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```